# InternetErrorDlg for X-Forms_Based_Auth_Required

Tags: oauth, office365, wininet

When I'm sending request to O365 with `WinInet`, the server replies with `HTTP 403` and `X-Forms_Based_Auth_Required` header. However, `InternetErrorDlg` does nothing on it and silently returns 0. Same is happening when requesting OAuth-enabled sites.
What does `InternetErrorDlg` support?
Is there any "system/IE" way to handle all the stuff with web-based authentication, including smart-cards, pins, storing passwords/auth-cookies etc.? Or this all must be implemented manually?

Comment: What kind of request were you handling? If you were using Office 365 REST API, you need to authenticate it with OAuth. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-app-authentication-tasks) is an helpful link for your reference.

Comment: thank you, but (1) I use same SOAP API for SharePoint 2010, 2013 and SharePoint Online aka SharePoint from Office 365; (2) headers from 403 response say nothing about OAuth - only some x-forms auth - this can be something different, can't it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313069(v=office.12).aspx and (3) my question is about InternetErrorDlg - what auth models does it support?